# Is there a symbol that takes the absolute value of each component of a matrix or vector in the linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors, absolute-value

Is there a symbol that takes the absolute value of each component of a matrix or vector in the linear algebra?

For example, Abs$(-1,-2)=(│-1│,│-2│)= (1,2)$

Comment: You could just define one

Comment: This is something that is rarely needed in mathematics. For the common uses of vectors and matrices, this is an ad-hoc operation, not something that arises naturally. Authors have likely invented notations for it several times, but because it is so rare, no one remembers them, and they have not become conventions. Therefore as Shubham Johri says, you can just invent your own, making sure to explain it to your audience when you use it.